# Add a class to each select of DateTimeType in a symfony form

Tags: symfony

Here is the form type that I have:
// src/Form/Type/TaskType.php

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use App\Entity\Task;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('task', TextType::class, array(
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'myclass'],
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'dueDate', DateType::class, array(
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'myclass'],
                )
            )
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)            
        ;

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Here is the view:

```
{# templates/task/new.html.twig #}
<div class="form-control">
    {{ form_label(form.task) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.task) }}

    <small>{{ form_help(form.task) }}</small>

    <div class="form-error">
        {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
    </div>  
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ form_label(form.dueDate) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.dueDate) }}

    <small>{{ form_help(form.dueDate) }}</small>

    <div class="form-error">
        {{ form_errors(form.dueDate) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The class "myclass" is added to the div containing all the select boxes and I want it to be applied to each select. If it is not possible to configure that in the form type there must be a way to break down the statement "form_widget(form.dueDate)" in the view so that I can pass the class to each select, and I cannot find that in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Smtngs like?:
= form_widget(form.createdAt.date, { attr: { class: "input-small datepicker" } })
= form_widget(form.createdAt.time, { attr: { class: "input-small" } })

Comment: @ZloyPotroh, it works, thanks.

Comment: Filled out the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we speak about DateTimeType, then you can use the following example:

```
= form_widget(form.dueDate.date, { attr: { class: 'myclass' } }) 
= form_widget(form.dueDate.time, { attr: { class: 'myclass' } })
```

Otherwise DateType can be split like:

```
= form_widget(form.dueDate.day, { attr: { class: 'myclass' } }) 
= form_widget(form.dueDate.month, { attr: { class: 'myclass' } })
= form_widget(form.dueDate.year, { attr: { class: 'myclass' } })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `class` to **every** `DateTimeType` in the application, a [form type extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) is a cleaner approach.

From the docs:

> They have 2 main use-cases:
>
> 2. You want to add a specific feature to a single form type.

So, the main benefits are that there's no need to pass the `attr` to each field configuration or the `form` render functions, and that it will automatically apply the class to any compound form that uses these types: `DateTimeType`, `BirthdayType`, etc.

```
namespace App\Form\Type\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class DateTimeAddClassExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    const WIDGET_CLASS = 'myclass';

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // Apply only if it's going to be rendered as 'select'
        if ('choice' == $options['widget']) {
            // Child fields of interest, add less used fields if desired
            foreach (['month', 'year', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'] as $field) {
                // We can check the options, but the view has already been built
                if (isset($view->children[$field])) {
                    $this->mergeAttrs($view->children[$field]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Merge our attribute with those defined in the field
     */
    private function mergeAttrs(&$child)
    {
        $child->vars['attr'] = array_merge(
          $child->vars['attr'],
          ['class' => self::WIDGET_CLASS]
        );
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [
          DateType::class,
          TimeType::class,
        ];
    }
}
```